# IE7 CSS Floating Issues

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, css-float

I'm having issues with a site I'm designing in IE7, particularly with medium to lower sized resolutions. There's a **nav** element floated to the left in a div, **#content_inside**. **#page**, holding actual content, then fits around the floated **nav**. Now, with particular resolutions, the **#page** content drops down below **nav**, which doesn't make sense since **#page** is not a floated element at all. I've included a link below for reference.

The other issue is the way IE7 is rendering images, those most affected being at the bottom of the page. The edges seem choppy and low-quality. Is this a known issue? It doesn't appear in any other browser on any other platform.

I believe the floating issue may occur in other IE versions, as well.

I didn't notice any of this until I viewed the website at the client's workplace, where they're running IE7 on Windows XP. I've tried plenty of fixes and the problems persist, so any help is appreciated.

Address: http://alexjewell.com/clients/klineman/

Thanks a lot.

PS - If it helps, the site is done in HTML5.

Comment: If the site is done in HTML5 I suggest you tell them to upgrade to Firefox or Chrome. Also they should definitely update to IE8 just for security reasons. There seems to be an issue where your main.css is being interpreted as an image when i try to view it in chrome.

Comment: Forgive me if this is an obvious blunder of mine, but can you not apply `float:left` to `#page`?

Answer (score 1):

I have to be honest, this seems simple enough for you not to be running into issues like this.

With respect to HTML5, I recommend you read [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/semanticsinhtml5) for dealing with IE7.

It seems that you have not given this page a width. Is that on purpose?

I wrote [a standard simple way of creating a 2 column layout](http://alexandergutierrez.info/stretch-background-color-in-a-two-col-layout) that I think can help you out.

Hope this all made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easier to use another div tag instead of the nav tag? IE may not recognize this because it's HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Change your  `#page`

```
#page{
    padding: 185px 10% 32px 350px;
}
```

to

```
#page
{
    margin-top: 185px;
    margin-left: 350px;
}
```

Its better to use margin for these sorts of things.